# Переход с общим элементом

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity, transition

Цель сделать переход между окнами с общим элементом (изображением). Нужно из окна А перейти в окно B с общим изображением (изображение ниже).

Activity A (переход через секунду):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
        Transition transition = TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.ico_transition);
        getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this , ActivityB.class);
                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.
                        makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ActivityA.this , new Pair<View, String>(image , IMAGE_ICO_NAME));
                startActivity(intent , options.toBundle());
                finish();
            }
        } , 1000);
    }
    else{
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this , ActivityB.class));
                finish();
            }
        } , 1000);
    }
```

res/transition/ico_transition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:duration="1000">
    <changeImageTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

Activity B:

```
private void initAnimation(){
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ico);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Transition transition = getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition();

        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(image , StartActivity.IMAGE_ICO_NAME);

        transition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {
                transition.removeListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Код как бы работает. Но работает не корректно. Встречаются такие проблемы как на фото 3. Может я что то делают не правильно или не до конца? что посоветуете?

[image: Activity A][image: Activity B][image: Failed (запечатлен при переходе ViewFlipper)]

Comment: Прошу прощение, но в чём конкретно проблема? аватарка короны всюду идентична. Если проблема у вас с каким-то неизменным элементом, попробуйте использовать `static final` модификаторы для поля

Comment: @dred проблема в том что анимация происходит не плавно. Зависает. Иногда результат не тот или как видели с background проблема (она должна быть белой). Это все заставляет задуматься о правильности кода

Comment: Если проблема с плавностью, то тут может быть многое, например, приложение ест слишком много памяти, либо у вас нет деления на потоки. Например, жмете на кнопку, должна произойти анимация, а программа отрабатывает само нажатие. Ну и так далее. Может задержка в 1000 слишком большая?

Comment: @Dred насчёт потоков мне нужно делать это самостоятельно? Или оно само? В примерах я ничего такого не видел